# Upload can't complete on medium and large files

Tags: 2010, file-upload, web-config

I have a problem related to the file upload into SharePoint.

When a user tries to upload that is ~ 5MB, everything is OK, the file is getting uploaded and the user can use the file.

In the case of a file over 10MB, the browser never gets to upload completely the file, and finally gets a timeout from the server.

- The web.config of the web application is OK. (executionTimeout="999999" and maxRequestLength="51200")
- The web application allows files
  under 50MB to be uploaded.
- The LAYOUTS web.config is OK for the
  Upload.aspx location. (executionTimeout="999999" and maxRequestLength="2097151")
- I am in a local environment, so the transfer is really quick (1000mbits)

I have fairly complex environment :

- 2 WFE
- 2 APP Servers
- FBA Authentication through Claims
- Novel Access Manager for the SSO
- 2 Domain names for the same web application (Web Application extension, no Alternate access mapping)

What am I doing wrong ? Is there an element in the config that I am missing ? I would understand if that was about the max upload size.  In my case I don't even want to extend the max upload size, I just want it to be respected !

I am at my limits concerning that, and I would really love an answer on that one !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact a timeout with the Novell Access Manager. Not related at all to SharePoint!  No intervention on the SharePoint server!